# Block access to site for upgrade

Tags: symfony

Do you know if i can (easly) "block" access to my production site for do an upgrade of code with symfony2 ?

Somthing like: All pages of my site display: "Site is in maintenance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact rules: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

@ elnur: with juste

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/the/maintenance/page.html
```

we have infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it with the Apache HTTP server is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/the/maintenance/page.html [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will display the maintenance page for any URL of your app.

You can comment and uncomment these lines when you need them and reload — not restart — the server to update its configuration. For example, in Debian/Ubuntu you would do:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to add the `[L]` flag. Fixed now.